# fullcalendar multiple month calendar views

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

What am I doing wrong here? [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/69/)

What I am trying to accomplish, instead of seeing three February months, I want to see February, March, April on the same page. Then when I click on next arrow, I want to see May, June July .. .etc.
Am I not addressing month correctly?

```
 $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
month:m
});
```

where m is an integer that represents the months...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated fiddle for you `code` http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/72/

you can use full calendar `gotoDate` [function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/)

Comment: Thank you..  just noticed.. when you click next arrow.. months are not adjusting right... =\ .. same with going to previous 3..

Comment: hmm when i click next button I should see May June July.. then when next is clicked August September October
when I click prev I should see November December January

Comment: right now what i see is it starts off with Feb march April (this is greaT!)
but then it goes on to the next as march april may

Comment: okkz.. now check.. i guess this is as `required `http://fiddle.jshell.net/0ft019xj/72/